# How to clear or erase, filled color from image?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am beginner to QT. Trying to fill color on top of image. For every 10 sec I want to fill different colors on the same area.My issue is, Since previously filled color still exists on the image, colors are overlapping every time.How can I clear the color before fill again.

GraphicsView_Layout .h

```
    class GraphicsView_Layout : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

          int mTimer;
          QImage* mfloorImg;

          protected:
          void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
          void Fill_Area_With_Color(float* nPmv)
    };
```

GraphicsView_Layout .cpp

```
    GraphicsView_Layout ::GraphicsView_Layout (QWidget *parent)
            : QWidget(parent)
     {
        ui.setupUi(this);

        mfloorImg=new QImage("./img.jpg");
        mTimer=startTimer(10000);

     }

    //Timer to update color
    void GraphicsView_Layout::timerEvent(QTimerEvent* event)
    {
       float nPmv[5]={0.1,-0.5,1,3,0};
       Fill_Area_With_Color(nPmv);
    }

    void GraphicsView_Layout::Fill_Area_With_Color(float* nPmv)
    {
         QPainter painter(mfloorImg);
         QColor areaColor;
         int nPos_X=20;
         int nPos_Y=30;
         int g_area_count=8;
         int nblock_count=20;

         //I want to clear previous color before filling again
         //But Erase not happening
         for(int i=0;i<g_area_count;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<nblock_count;j++)
             {
                painter.eraseRect(QRect(nPos_X+(i*j),nPos_Y+(i*j),28,24));
             }
         }           

         //Fill Color
         for(int i=0;i<g_area_count;i++)
         {
             areaColor=Get_Area_Color(nPmv[i]); //Get area color
             for(int j=0;j<nblock_count;j++)
             {
                painter.fillRect(QRect(nPos_X+(i*j),nPos_Y+(i*j),28,24),QBrush(areaColor));
             }
         }           
      }
```

Comment: `eraseRect` uses background color for erasing, which defaults to transparent, so it has no effect unless you set the background color in `QPainter::setBackground`. This code only fills the `QImage`, but it doesn't really use it anywhere. How do you display the image? If you paint it on the widget manually in `paintEvent`, you need to call `repaint()` or `update()` to force repaint. Also check out `QGraphicsView` and `QTimer` (just in case you don't know about them).

Comment: Thank you. I display the image using QGraphicsView. Once I fill color on image I will insert the image in to graphics view. I found a temporary solution now. Instead of repainting on the same image, I am loading new image every time. So that I don't have to erase.